# In wxpython, how to set position of objects within a wxScrolledWindow

Tags: python, user-interface, wxpython, wxwidgets

I am writing a kicad plugin, and I need to create a GUI for this plugin. Because kicad uses wxpython, that is what I am using.

I have already figured out that placing my ui items using the layout sizers just isn't gonna give me the control I need to create the window I want. I know I can set the position of elements, and have been using that to create the ui I need.

The problem however, is that my window gets bigger than what would be reasonable (in some situations). Therefore I want to make it scrollable.

I have been playing around with wxformbuilder, and I found the wxScrolledWindow. That got me this far:
[image]

This is roughly what I want, except, when you want to place stuff within the scrolledWindow, you have to place one of the "sizers" in it (as far as I can tell at least), in which you place your buttons. The problem with that is, that, to my knowledge, setting the position of buttons in any of the sizers just has no effect at all.

So, my question is: how do I achieve this effect? and, is this even possible?

edit:

As an example of what I am trying to put within the scrolledwindow, this is a rough version of the ui I want to create (and want to be scrollable). (I want to eventually have, probably an icon button above each of the checkbox columns to indicate what they are for).

[image]
The final result would need to look something like this (the white squares being small images / buttons, also, in reality being not on the window bar,but in its own not scrolling section):

[image]

An example of something I wasn't able to achieve using sizers is, getting those checkboxes so close together, without making them appear off center. Different widgets seem to have different sizes, and checkboxes without border are especially small, so they end up appearing off center, example:

[image]

Also, those images above each column of checkboxes, which don't scroll, need to line up with the X coordinates of those scrolling checkboxes, which also seems very non trivial. Though also really hard to get right if I could give everything exact coords, so I might need to give up on that specific idea of making those not scrollable.

Comment: Sizers can have gaps, empty slots and fixed number of slots, some which may contain widgets and others not. To some extent your asking, how long is a piece of string? Mock up what you wish to achieve, so people have some idea of what you're aiming for.

Comment: I edited the question to give examples of what I want to achieve.

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (see this [code of a wxPython application](https://pastebin.com/pn86mFiK)). People will be able to help much better if they don't have to start from scratch

Comment: A minimal reproducable example of what though? The window with the scrollwindow and 3 buttons below it? The thing I want to put inside of that scrollwindow? The widgets which aren't aligned because they are different sizes? The final product which I don't have because I don't know how to make it?

Comment: @TT-392, I am curious whether you had been trying box sizer and you need flex grid one. Sizers are extremely useful as they give you support for different resolution, theme, etc.

Comment: I'd hazard a guess that you need a horizontal sizer and a `GridBagSizer` for the boxes, for `each` line. A tip: when adding a widget to a sizer, you can influence its internal position with wx.ALIGN_CENTER or wx.ALIGN_CENTRE
wx.ALIGN_LEFT
wx.ALIGN_RIGHT
wx.ALIGN_RIGHT
wx.ALIGN_TOP
wx.ALIGN_BOTTOM
wx.ALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL or wx.ALIGN_CENTRE_VERTICAL
wx.ALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL or wx.ALIGN_CENTRE_HORIZONTAL

Comment: So.... the answer to my actual question is no? But the effect I am trying to achieve should be possible with sizers.

Comment: Though, I guess looking at it now, I think my question was worded poorly in the title, I should have clarified that I was talking about absolute positions

Comment: Also, I have been playing around with wxformbuilder, and manged to find the wx.ALIGN_CENTER thing. And I managed to get most of the stuff into place using a some flexGridSizers. I plan to answer / edit my question soon with working code.